# How to get a list of installed Jenkins plugins with name and version pair

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

How can I get a list of installed Jenkins plugins?

I searched the Jenkins Remote Access API document, but it was not found. Should I use Jenkins' CLI? Is there a document or example?

Answer (score 247):

You can retrieve the information using the [Jenkins Script Console](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Jenkins+Script+Console) which is accessible by visiting `http://<jenkins-url>/script`. (Given that you are logged in and have the required permissions).

[image: Screenshot of the Script Console]

Enter the following *Groovy script* to iterate over the installed plugins and print out the relevant information:

```
Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins.each{
  plugin -> 
    println ("${plugin.getDisplayName()} (${plugin.getShortName()}): ${plugin.getVersion()}")
}
```

It will print the results list like this (clipped):

[image: SScreenshot of script output]

This solutions is similar to [one of the answers above](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9822818/1153530) in that it uses Groovy, but here we are using the script console instead. The script console is extremely helpful when using Jenkins.

**Update**

If you prefer a sorted list, you can call this [`sort` method](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Iterable.html#sort(groovy.lang.Closure)):

```
def pluginList = new ArrayList(Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins)
pluginList.sort { it.getShortName() }.each{
  plugin -> 
    println ("${plugin.getDisplayName()} (${plugin.getShortName()}): ${plugin.getVersion()}")
}
```

Adjust the Closure to your liking (e.g. here it is sorted by the shortName, in the example it is sorted by DisplayName)

Comment: Of all the answers, this is the most useful for filing a plugin bug report; it can be done using the standard web UI and gives the result in a format that can be easily pasted into the "Environment" field.

Comment: Great answer for quickly creating a plugins.txt for docker Jenkins!

Comment: It might be useful to add sorting so that the list of plugins is consistent:

`Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins.sort({it.getDisplayName()}).each{
  plugin -> 
    println ("${plugin.getDisplayName()} (${plugin.getShortName()}): ${plugin.getVersion()}")
}`

Comment: Per Allessandro's answer you may need to coerce the List to another type in a new object to sort it. https://stackoverflow.com/a/48198920/3794873

Comment: This is the answer we've switched to locally instead of my XPath suggestion above, wrapped with a curl request and some pruning of built from source plugins we use this approach to generate the plugins.txt for our docker image as mentioned by @ErikEnglund above

```echo 'script=Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins.each{ plugin ->
  println ("${plugin.getShortName()}:${plugin.getVersion()}")
}
null' \
    | no_proxy=localhost curl --netrc --silent --data-binary @- -X POST "http://localhost:8080/jenkins/scriptText"
    | sort > plugins.txt
```

Comment: The sort doesn't work, it's an unmodifiableMap these days.  Use: ```jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getPluginManager().getPlugins().stream().sorted().each {
  println "${it.getShortName()} | ${it.getVersion()} | ${it.getDisplayName()}"
}```

Comment: You can further determine which of the "installed" plugins are disabled by inspecting the .isActive() method.  E.g. `${it.isActive()}` will be true if the plugin is active, false if it is not enabled.  `.isEnabled()` is also interesting because the plugin may be ENABLED but not active meaning it will be loaded the next time jenkins starts, or the configuration is reloaded.

Comment: For using this with Scriptler I had to insert this line at the top: `import jenkins.model.*`

Answer (score 107):

*These days I use the same approach as the answer described by @Behe below instead, updated link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35292719/3423146 (old link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35292719/1597808)*

---

You can use the API in combination with depth, XPath, and wrapper arguments.

The following will query the API of the pluginManager to list all plugins installed, but only to return their shortName and version attributes. You can of course retrieve additional fields by adding '|' to the end of the XPath parameter and specifying the pattern to identify the node.

```
wget http://<jenkins>/pluginManager/api/xml?depth=1&xpath=/*/*/shortName|/*/*/version&wrapper=plugins
```

The wrapper argument is required in this case, because it's returning more than one node as part of the result, both in that it is matching multiple fields with the XPath and multiple plugin nodes.

It's probably useful to use the following URL in a browser to see what information on the plugins is available and then decide what you want to limit using XPath:

```
http://<jenkins>/pluginManager/api/xml?depth=1
```

Comment: Hi, Do you know how to get the list of plugins that are actually used by Jenkins jobs and Jenkins system rather than the complete list of installed plugins? Thanks

Comment: Not straight forward, but http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18138361/how-can-i-know-whether-the-plugin-is-used-by-any-jobs-in-jenkins might be of more use to you.

Automatically determining the type of each plugin in order to determine where to look or query jenkins likely requires a good deal of knowledge on the internals of jenkins. But if you are willing to retrieve the list of plugins and create the config file manually or create a mapping of known plugins to type and generate the config file using this, it should do what you want.

Comment: Worked well for me on Mac OS X. I wanted to convert the output to a plain text list, so used some Perl regex to strip the tags: `curl 'http://192.168.197.133:8080/pluginManager/api/xml?depth=1&xpath=/*/*/shortName|/*/*/version&wrapper=plugins' | perl -pe 's/.*?<shortName>([\w-]+).*?<version>([^<]+)()(<\/\w+>)+/\1 \2\n/g'`

Comment: @dbailey Really useful! Thanks

Comment: Alternative in JSON format: `curl -s -k "http://jenkins/pluginManager/api/json?depth=1" | jq '.plugins[]|{shortName, version,longName}' -c`

Comment: Improved JSON curl: `curl -sSL -k "http://jenkins/pluginManager/api/json?depth=1" | jq '.plugins[]|{shortName, version,longName}' -c | sort` (follows 301 redirects, sorted)

Comment: Alternative in JSON format _without_ jq: `curl -s "http://<jenkins>/pluginManager/api/json?depth=1&tree=plugins\[shortName,version,longName\]"`

Comment: These days I'd tend to use a curl query to the script console to generate the text output used for my docker container:

`echo 'script=Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins.each{ plugin ->
  println ("${plugin.getShortName()}:${plugin.getVersion()}")
};
null' | no_proxy=localhost curl --silent --data-binary @- -X POST \
        "http://<user>:<password>@localhost:8080/jenkins/scriptText" \
    | sort | grep -v -e " (private.*-root)$" > plugins.txt`

Comment: I believe that this requires administration privileges, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Confirmed that this requires admin privileges per [the 2016-05-11 security advisory](https://jenkins.io/security/advisory/2016-05-11).

Comment: Thank you @dbailey. 

It worked perfectly fine for me.
I did this.. open this URL from Browser as our Jenkins is sso enabled.

https://<jenkins>/pluginManager/api/xml?depth=1

Saved the xml and then ran this in PowerShell:

<pre>
$XPath="/localPluginManager/plugin"
Select-Xml -Path "C:\workpace\plugin.xml" -XPath $XPath | Select-Object -ExpandProperty Node | Select-Object shortName, version
<code>

Answer (score 39):

**Jenkins 1.588** (2<sup>nd</sup> of November, 2014) & **1.647** (4<sup>th</sup> of February, 2016)

- Jenkins > Manage Jenkins

  [image]
- System Information

  [image]
- Plugins

  [image]

Comment: This is very simple, and I am able to get the list from DEV and PRD server, paste them into Excel and compare their versions side by side.

Answer (score 27):

The Jenkins CLI supports listing all installed plugins:

`java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ list-plugins`

Comment: This won't list the state of the plugin.

Comment: And the `list-plugins` CLI command does not require the user to have the _Overall/RunScripts permission_ as `groovy` command does.

Comment: This does not appear to work with an API token if the user/token is not "Overall/Administrator".

Comment: @JoséAndias: yes, but Overall/Administer seems to be needed, right ?

Answer (score 27):

If you're working in a docker environment and want to output the plugin list in a plugins.txt format in order to pass that to the install_scripts.sh use these scripts in the `http://{jenkins}/script` console:

1. This version is useful for getting specific package version

```
Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins.each{
  plugin -> 
    println ("${plugin.getShortName()}:${plugin.getVersion()}")
}
```

2. If you only want the plugin with the latest version you can use this (thanks @KymikoLoco for the tip)

```
Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins.each{
  plugin -> 
    println ("${plugin.getShortName()}:latest")
}
```

Comment: If you want to get the latest versions of all the plugins, you can extend this to only get the short name and add `:latest` to the end:
`println ("${plugin.getShortName()}:latest")`

Answer (score 25):

Use Jenkins CLI like this:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://[jenkins_server] groovy = < pluginEnumerator.groovy
```

`=` in the call means *'read from standard input'*. *pluginEnumerator.groovy* contains the following Groovy code:

```
println "Running plugin enumerator"
println ""
def plugins = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getPluginManager().getPlugins()
plugins.each {println "${it.getShortName()} - ${it.getVersion()}"}
println ""
println "Total number of plugins: ${plugins.size()}"
```

If you would like to play with the code, [here's Jenkins Java API documentation](http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/index.html).

Comment: @user1284795, was this helpful?

Comment: Hi, do you know how to get the plugins used by Jenkins system and Jenkins job instead of getting all plugins installed? I would like this to help me uninstall all unused plugins. Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. @user1164061, I don't think there is a any difference between plugins visible to a job vs to the server. There is an `isActive()` api that you can use in the groovy script in this answer to get the state of the plugin. See http://javadoc.jenkins-ci.org/hudson/PluginWrapper.html#isActive().

Comment: This answer gets my vote to be the accepted answer.

Answer (score 20):

The answers here were somewhat incomplete. And I had to compile information from other sources to actually acquire the plugin list.

### 1. Get the Jenkins CLI

The Jenkins CLI will allow us to interact with our Jenkins server from the command line. We can get it with a simple curl call.

```
curl 'localhost:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar' > jenkins-cli.jar
```

### 2. Create a Groovy script for parsing (thanks to malenkiy_scot)

Save the following as `plugins.groovy`.

```
def plugins = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getPluginManager().getPlugins()
plugins.each {println "${it.getShortName()}: ${it.getVersion()}"}
```

### 3. Call the Jenkins API for plugin results

Call the Jenkins server (`localhost:8080` here) with your login username and password while referencing the Groovy script:

```
java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 groovy --username "admin" --password "admin" = < plugins.groovy > plugins.txt
```

The output to plugins.txt looks like this:

```
ace-editor: 1.1
ant: 1.5
antisamy-markup-formatter: 1.5
authentication-tokens: 1.3
blueocean-autofavorite: 1.0.0
blueocean-commons: 1.1.4
blueocean-config: 1.1.4
blueocean-dashboard: 1.1.4
blueocean-display-url: 2.0
blueocean-events: 1.1.4
blueocean-git-pipeline: 1.1.4
blueocean-github-pipeline: 1.1.4
blueocean-i18n: 1.1.4
blueocean-jwt: 1.1.4
blueocean-personalization: 1.1.4
blueocean-pipeline-api-impl: 1.1.4
blueocean-pipeline-editor: 0.2.0
blueocean-pipeline-scm-api: 1.1.4
blueocean-rest-impl: 1.1.4
```

Comment: The above commands should run on your workstation and not on a Jenkins job

Comment: The command seems to result in "ERROR: anonymous is missing the Overall/Read permission" in latest versions.. instead passing the auth before worked for me

java -jar jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080 -auth "admin:<password>" groovy = < plugins.groovy

Answer (score 16):

With `curl` and `jq`:

```
curl -s <jenkins_url>/pluginManager/api/json?depth=1 \
  | jq -r '.plugins[] | "\(.shortName):\(.version)"' \
  | sort
```

This command gives output in a format used by special Jenkins `plugins.txt` file which enables you to pre-install dependencies (e.g. in a docker image):

```
ace-editor:1.1
ant:1.8
apache-httpcomponents-client-4-api:4.5.5-3.0
```

Example of a `plugins.txt`: https://github.com/hoto/jenkinsfile-examples/blob/master/source/jenkins/usr/share/jenkins/plugins.txt

Answer (score 12):

[Behe's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815273/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-jenkins-plugins-with-name-and-version-pair/35292719#35292719) with sorting plugins did not work on my Jenkins machine. I received the error `java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException` due to trying to sort an immutable collection i.e. `Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins`. Simple fix for the code:

```
List<String> jenkinsPlugins = new ArrayList<String>(Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins);
jenkinsPlugins.sort { it.displayName }
              .each { plugin ->
                   println ("${plugin.shortName}:${plugin.version}")
              }
```

Use the `http://<jenkins-url>/script` URL to run the code.

Comment: I ran into this as well using a different version of Jenkins than the first system I tested it on. For v2.81 the top answer worked, but for LTS v2.83.x and any newer versions it gave the error you mentioned while your code still worked.

Comment: One thing I just noticed is you are sorting based on the `displayName` while printing out the `shortName`, this was very confusing as some plugins aren't alphabetically the same for both, and it results in a list that doesn't appear sorted. Changing `it.displayName` to `it.shortName` solves this nicely.

Answer (score 10):

If you are a Jenkins administrator you can use the Jenkins system information page:

```
http://<jenkinsurl>/systemInfo
```

Comment: `/systeminfo` doesn't work (HTTP 404) on Jenkins 1.594

Comment: Try `http://localhost:8080/systemInfo` --some servers are case-sensitive. Note also that it requires the currently logged in user to have Overall/Administer permission.

Answer (score 4):

From the Jenkins home page:

1. Click **Manage Jenkins**.
2. Click **Manage Plugins**.
3. Click on the **Installed** tab.

Or

1. Go to the Jenkins URL directly: {Your Jenkins base URL}/pluginManager/installed

Comment: The "installed plugins" page doesn't necessarily reflect the real plugin status. E.g. you might re-enable a plugin, and see the plugin checked, while the plugin is still disabled until Jenkins-Restart. Therefore, the only 100% solutions are http://<jenkinsurl>/systeminfo and the API query answers, imho.

Answer (score 4):

Sharing another option found [here](https://github.com/jenkinsci/docker) with credentials

```
JENKINS_HOST=username:password@myhost.com:port
curl -sSL "http://$JENKINS_HOST/pluginManager/api/xml?depth=1&xpath=/*/*/shortName|/*/*/version&wrapper=plugins" | perl -pe 's/.*?<shortName>([\w-]+).*?<version>([^<]+)()(<\/\w+>)+/\1 \2\n/g'|sed 's/ /:/'
```

Comment: as above, but without the versions, and sorted.

`curl -sSL "http://127.0.0.1:8080/pluginManager/api/xml?depth=1&xpath=/*/*/shortName|/*/*/version&wrapper=plugins" | perl -pe 's/.*?<shortName>([\w-]+).*?<version>([^<]+)()(<\/\w+>)+/\1 \n/g' | sort`

Answer (score 4):

I wanted a solution that could run on master without any auth requirements and didn't see it here. I made a quick bash script that will pull out all the versions from the plugins dir.

```
if [ -f $JENKINS_HOME/plugin_versions.txt ]; then
  rm $JENKINS_HOME/plugin_versions.txt
fi

for dir in $JENKINS_HOME/plugins/*/; do
  dir=${dir%*/}
  dir=${dir##*/}
  version=$(grep Plugin-Version $JENKINS_HOME/plugins/$dir/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | awk -F': ' '{print $2}')
  echo $dir $version >> $JENKINS_HOME/plugin_versions.txt
done
```

Comment: `grep Plugin-Version */META-INF/MANIFEST.MF | sed -e 's!/META-INF/MANIFEST.MF:Plugin-Version: !:!g' > ../plugins2.txt`

Answer (score 3):

Another option for Python users:

```
from jenkinsapi.jenkins import Jenkins

#get the server instance
jenkins_url = 'http://<jenkins-hostname>:<jenkins-port>/jenkins'
server = Jenkins(jenkins_url, username = '<user>', password = '<password>')

#get the installed plugins as list and print the pairs
plugins_dictionary = server.get_plugins().get_plugins_dict()
for key, value in plugins_dictionary.iteritems():
    print "Plugin name: %s, version: %s" %(key, value.version)
```

Answer (score 2):

I think these are not good enough answer(s)... many involve a couple of extra under-the-hood steps. Here's how I did it.

```
sudo apt-get install jq
```

...because the JSON output needs to be consumed after you call the API.

```
#!/bin/bash
server_addr = 'jenkins'
server_port = '8080'

curl -s -k "http://${server_addr}:${server_port}/pluginManager/api/json?depth=1" \
  | jq '.plugins[]|{shortName, version,longName,url}' -c | sort \
  > plugin-list

echo "dude, here's your list: "
cat plugin-list
```

Answer (score 1):

There are lots of way to fetch this information but I am writing two ways as below : -

**1. Get the jenkins cli.**

The jenkins CLI will allow us to interact with our jenkins server from the command line. We can get it with a simple curl call.

`curl 'localhost:8080/jnlpJars/jenkins-cli.jar' > jenkins-cli.jar`

**2. Create a groovy script. OR from jenkins script console**

We need to create a groovy script to parse the information we receive from the jenkins API. This will output each plugin with its version. Save the following as plugins.groovy.

`def plugins = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getPluginManager().getPlugins()
plugins.each {println "${it.getShortName()}: ${it.getVersion()}"}`

Answer (score 1):

You can be also interested what updates are available for plugins. For that, you have to merge the data about installed plugins with information about updates available here https://updates.jenkins.io/current/update-center.json .

To parse the downloaded file as a JSON you have to read online the second line (which is huge).

Answer (score 1):

```
# list of plugins in sorted order
# Copy this into your Jenkins script console
    def plugins = jenkins.model.Jenkins.instance.getPluginManager().getPlugins()

    List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>()

    i = 0
    plugins.each {
      ++i
      //println " ${i}  ${it.getShortName()}: ${it.getVersion()}"
      list.add("${it.getShortName()}: ${it.getVersion()}")
    }

    list.sort{it}
    i = 0
    for (String item : list) {
      i++
      println(" ${i} ${item}")
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If Jenkins run in a the Jenkins Docker container you can use this command line in Bash:

```
java -jar /var/jenkins_home/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar -s http://localhost:8080/ list-plugins --username admin --password `/bin/cat /var/jenkins_home/secrets/initialAdminPassword`
```

Answer (score 0):

For Jenkins version 2.125 the following worked.

NOTE: Replace sections that say USERNAME and APIKEY with a valid UserName and APIKey for that corresponding user.
The API key for a user is available via
*Manage Users* → *Select User* → *API Key* option.

You may have to extend the sleep if your Jenkins installation takes longer to start.

The initiation `yum update -y` will upgrade the version as well if you installed Jenkins using yum as well.

```
#JENKINS AUTO UPDATE SCRIPT link this script into a cron
##############
!/bin/bash
sudo yum update -y
sleep 120
UPDATE_LIST=$( sudo /usr/bin/java -jar /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar -auth [USERNAME:APIKEY] -s http://localhost:8080/ list-plugins | grep -e ')$' | awk '{ print $1 }' );
if [ ! -z "${UPDATE_LIST}" ]; then
    echo Updating Jenkins Plugins: ${UPDATE_LIST};
    sudo /usr/bin/java -jar /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar -auth [USERNAME:APIKEY] -s http://localhost:8080/ install-plugin ${UPDATE_LIST};
    sudo /usr/bin/java -jar /var/cache/jenkins/war/WEB-INF/jenkins-cli.jar -auth [USERNAME:APIKEY] -s http://localhost:8080/ safe-restart;
fi
##############
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm a little surprised this wasn't mentioned here, but the pluginusage URL from the https://plugins.jenkins.io/plugin-usage-plugin/ seems pretty nice and is available to regular users, no admin needed (just to install the plugin). Good to use to check if the Jenkins server you're using has a particular plugin:
`http://<jenkinsurl>/pluginusage`

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Master Server its quite simple. All you have to do is to go to Jenkins directory inside that you will find plugins folder, It contains all the list and data you need.
In my case it is at `/var/lib/jenkins/plugins`

Answer (score -1):

There is a table listing all the plugins installed and whether or not they are enabled at http://jenkins/systemInfo

However, you need administrative rights for this.