# How to get a list of installed hudson plugins with name and version?

Tags: jenkins, hudson, hudson-plugins, hudson-api

Is there any way to get the list of installed hudson plugins? 
"Manage hudson">"Manage Plugins" gives the list but is there some API to fetch the list with version number ?
Or is the installed plugin list stored somewhere in the file system?

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815273/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-jenkins-plugins-with-name-and-version-pair

Comment: Looks like your question is already answered here? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815273/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-jenkins-plugins-with-name-and-version-pair