# is there any pip freeze equivalent for jenkins plugins which can be used to pre-install plugins in jenkins docker image?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

In python world there is useful tool like `pip freeze` which dumps all currently installed python packages into a core-support plugin format. This dump can then be used to configure a new virtual environment for a new python installation.

Is there anything similar for Jenkins docker images?

I understand from the [official jenkins docker image](https://hub.docker.com/_/jenkins/) docs that it can accept a core-support plugin format file to pre-install plugins. How can i **generate** that file myself from an existing jenkins installation that i already have?

Comment: Similar to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815273/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-jenkins-plugins-with-name-and-version-pair).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following Groovy code can be entered into the *Script Console* available under *Manage Jenkins* and will output said list:

```java
Jenkins.instance.pluginManager.plugins.sort().each{ plugin ->
  println "${plugin.getShortName()}:${plugin.getVersion()}"
}
```

> ace-editor:1.1
>   analysis-collector:1.49
>   analysis-core:1.81
>   ansicolor:0.4.3
>   ...