# How can I determine the syntax version without management permissions?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-declarative-pipeline

How can I determine what version of the [declarative pipeline syntax](https://plugins.jenkins.io/pipeline-model-definition) is available to me when writing a Jenkinsfile if I do not have the permissions needed to list the plugins in the Jenkins server?

I am trying to write a Jenkinsfile using the declarative syntax, but cannot tell if the errors I encounter are because I am misinterpreting the documentation or if I am referencing documentation for a newer version than available on the box.

I have access to Jenkins server to configure and run a build.  However, I have no management or script permissions over Jenkins itself, so none of the options on [How to get a list of installed jenkins plugins with name and version pair?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9815273/how-to-get-a-list-of-installed-jenkins-plugins-with-name-and-version-pair) worked for me.

Perhaps there is a way to make my Jenkinsfile echo the relevant version information as part of its execution?  Or some easy syntax tests that (based on pass/failure) would prove which syntax version is available?

Comment: Hello,
I think if you show the errors you are getting it will be more simple to help you

Comment: @eranmeiri My concern isn't fixing my errors, I can figure those out to the point of getting a working build.  What I want to know is what version of the  syntax I have available so I know what documentation I can and cannot reference.

Comment: Do you have ssh access to Jenkins server?

Comment: @VitaliiVitrenko I do not

Answer (score 0):

This might be helpful, depending on version of Jenkins, but a note at the bottom said this was blocked more than a year ago. So there probably isn't a way to do it without admin access. You can use the REST API, CLI, or script console, but all fo these require admin access.

https://support.cloudbees.com/hc/en-us/articles/218756317-How-can-non-admin-users-view-the-installed-plugins-