# Jenkins Pipeline: No Such DSL Method ‘perfReport’ found

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-job-dsl

I am getting the error No such Dsl method ‘perfReport’ found

```
post {
always
// sh '1s -ltr target/jmeter/reports*
sh sh
mkdir -p target/jmeter_results/*
sh
"cp -a target/jmeter/reports/*/* target/imeter results/"
sh
'op -a target/jmeter/results/*.cav target/jmeter_results/results.txt*
"ep -a target/jmeter/logs/*.log target/jmeter_results/Jmeter.jmx.log* sh
'ls -ltr target/imeter results/' archiveArtifacts artifacts: 'target/imeter results/*, allowEmptyArchive: true, fingerprint: true, caseSensitive: true, onlyIf
publishHTML (target: [allowMissing: false, alwayslinkToLastBuild: true, keepAll: false, reportDir: "target/imeter results/. reportFiles:
index.html'
reportName:
"Performance Test Result*
//reportTitles:
])
perfReport errorFailedThreshold: 5, errorUnstableResponseTimeThreshold: 'results.txt:1000*, errorUnstableThreshold: 2, excludeRespe
changed {
notifybuildstatus (currentBuild.currentResult)
def notifybuildstatus (buildstatus)
def status
switch (buildStatus) {
case SUCCESS' :
status = ' GREEN*
break
case 'UNSTABLE*:
status = 'AMBER*
break
case FAILURE::
status break
"RED*
```

Answer (score 1):

This error can mean:

1. [The performance plugin](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/performance/) isn't installed on your jenkins. [This post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34590817/9498358) explains how you can see which plugins are installed.
2. You have a typo, and a property name is wrong, or the type of the value different than the expexted, e.g. the plugin expects a bool but you're passing a string.
   From your code, the value of `errorUnstableResponseTimeThreshold` has an asterisk (`*`) instead of the closing quote (`'`). That may be the cause. The command is truncated so it's hard to say if the other keys have valid values.
   You can try using the [pipeline snippet generator](https://www.jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/getting-started/#snippet-generator) to ensure your syntax is correct, but I'm not sure if it's supported for this plugin.